# How to make existing branch a child of a new branch

Tags: git

A few weeks ago I branched off of our develop branch to work on a story ([Agile term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story)).  Recently our release manager decided to have all branches related to a feature be children of the feature branch.

Is there an easy way to get from

```
develop
  |
  ---> My Branch
  |
  ---> Feature
```

To:

```
develop
  |
  ---> Feature
         |
         ---> My Branch
```

**EDIT**: I didn't realize that branches don't actually have parent/child relationships.  This follows the trend of half of my SO posts making me sound straight-up ignorant.  I appreciate the answers; they helped me find a good path forward.

Comment: Branches, in Git, do not have parent/child relationships. Only commits have parent/child relationships. These are fixed when you make the commits (because commits are permanent and can never be changed). You can *copy* a chain of commits, which is what `git rebase` does, and then make the branch label point to the tip-most of the new copies (which `git rebase` also does); that may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Rebase it in the wanted branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do anything, then `rebase` (as others have suggested) would probably be what to do.

But there's a good chance you don't have to do anything.

People get hung up on concepts like "parent branch", that simply don't exist in git.  There is no memory of what branch you were on when `My Branch` was created.  So only if the commit topology is actually wrong does anything need to be done.

Suppose you start with

```
x --- O <--(develop)
```

And you created your story branch, and maybe did some work.

```
x --- O <--(develop)
       \
        A <--(story)
```

Now if your release manager hadn't decided to group story branches into feature branches, you'd eventually merge `story` back to `develop`.  But instead you now have a feature branch,  But creating the feature branch doesn't change anything about the commits that exist.

```
x --- O <--(develop)(feature)
       \
        A <--(story)
```

and in fact, even if the feature branch had existed before the story branch, and you had checked it out and used that as your starting point when you created `story`... the picture would be exactly the same.  In this scenario, all that needs to happen is, when the `story` branch is done, you merge it to `feature` instead of to `develop`.  (Which, assuming `--no-ff`, gives

```
x --- O <--(develop)
      |
      |-- M <--(feature)
       \ /
        A <--(story)
```

and you have your "apparent" branch hierarchy.)

That's not to say that you'd *never* have to fix anything.  If there had been commits to `develop` between where `story` was created and where `feature` was created, you might indeed want to rebase `story` to make it consistent with the designated branch point for `feature`.  That would typically look like

```
rebase --onto feature develop story
```

(And then, ideally, you should retest each and every commit on the rewritten `story` branch. Which, if you have automated build/test tools, shouldn't be a big deal... and if you don't, you're not really doing agile...)

And going forward: once `feature` has been created, you'll want to use it as the starting point for additional `story` branches (a) to avoid accidentally incorporating other `develop` commits into `feature`, and (b) to reduce unnecessary merge conflicts when combining `story`s into `feature`.

Comment: Thank you -- I appreciate the extra level of though you've put into this.

Answer (score 0):

Branches do not have children, but if you want the commit at the current tip of `Feature` branch to be an ancestor of `My Branch`, you should first checkout `My Branch` and then rebase it on top of `Feature` branch.

```
git checkout My Branch
git rebase Feature
```

Note that if you want to maintain this relationship, then you must perform this rebase again every time `Feature` branch moves. That is, you must re-run the above two commands every time anyone makes a commit to `Feature` branch.